# How to create the same Activity Multiple times to have an effect like Google Chrome Tabs?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am creating a browser for Android and I want to duplicate my Activity for create a new multitasking task with the same activity.

```cs
Intent intent=new Intent(this,  MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This is my code, Please help.
Thanks

Comment: and it doesn't work, or?

Comment: Use fragments https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 1):

Use this and replace the *FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK* with *FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT*

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: If you think it has solved your problem mark it as answer for rest of the users to know

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this. Both are well described in Android's [Recents Screen guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents.html).

The first method is to use the intent flags:

```
final Intent newDocumentIntent = new Intent(this, NewDocumentActivity.class);
newDocumentIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
newDocumentIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(newDocumentIntent);
```

The second method is to use the [<activity>](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) attribute, [android:documentLaunchMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#dlmode).

Answer (score 0):

you can try 
FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
>
> This flag is used to create a new task and launch an activity into it.
>   This flag is always paired with either FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT or
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. In both cases these flags alone would search
>   through existing tasks for ones matching this Intent. Only if no such
>   task is found would a new task be created. When paired with
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK both of these behaviors are modified to
>   skip the search for a matching task and unconditionally start a new
>   task. When used with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK do not use this flag
>   unless you are implementing your own top-level application launcher.
>   Used in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to disable the
>   behavior of bringing an existing task to the foreground. When set, a
>   new task is always started to host the Activity for the Intent,
>   regardless of whether there is already an existing task running the
>   same thing.
>
> Because the default system does not include graphical task management,
>   you should not use this flag unless you provide some way for a user to
>   return back to the tasks you have launched. See
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT for details of this flag's use for creating
>   new document tasks.
>
> **> This flag is ignored if one of FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT is not also set.**

FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT

> This flag is used to open a document into a new task rooted at the
>   activity launched by this Intent. Through the use of this flag, or its
>   equivalent attribute, documentLaunchMode multiple instances of the
>   same activity containing different documents will appear in the recent
>   tasks list.
>
> The use of the activity attribute form of this, documentLaunchMode, is
>   preferred over the Intent flag described here. The attribute form
>   allows the Activity to specify multiple document behavior for all
>   launchers of the Activity whereas using this flag requires each Intent
>   that launches the Activity to specify it.
>
> Note that the default semantics of this flag w.r.t. whether the
>   recents entry for it is kept after the activity is finished is
>   different than the use of FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and
>   documentLaunchMode -- if this flag is being used to create a new
>   recents entry, then by default that entry will be removed once the
>   activity is finished. You can modify this behavior with
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_RETAIN_IN_RECENTS.