# FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY Vs FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT Vs FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK

Tags: java, android, android-intent

with some explanation when to use these.
Like I can use this code rating own App

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getApplication().getPackageName());
            Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
            // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
            goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            try {
                startActivity(goToMarket);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getApplication().getPackageName())));
            }
```

And without that my App is working the same. 
I'm new to android sorry if I ask something wrong.
Thanks

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY , https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT , https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK

Comment: bro but without that my App also work same

Comment: these don't define whether your app is going to work or not, these simply define how the activities are being launched and how they're being kept on the stack (if at all). You can see the differences if you launch various activities and then trying to hit the back button to go to the previous ones. Using the no_history one, for example, you won't be able to go back to the previous activity.

Comment: ok this is for FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY  But what for FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)

The activity is not kept on stack, when you navigate away it finishes and on hitting the back button from another activity, you won’t be able to return to this one. Careful no to start an activity for result ([startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))) from this activity, because the result will not be returned anywhere.

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT)

An activity that handles documents can use this attribute so that with every document you open you launch a separate instance of the same activity. If you check your recent apps, then you will see various screens of the same activity of your app, each using a different document.

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK)

This is not used by itself. Usually, it follows the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT. Where the new instance of the activity before would be added to an existing task, using the multiple task intent specifies that each new instance of the activity should be a separate task and show separately in the recent tasks screen.

These are basic differences/uses of the intent filters, but to understand them in greater detail, I think the official documentarians that I’ve linked are great at explaining that.

Comment: @SagarKhurana I prefer not to give out my personal information like that. Also, the time that I spend here is mainly on my breaks from work, so I can't really devote plenty of time. Is it a programming question you have? Consider posting it on a separate thread here. It's better to reach a wider audience as well!

Comment: I can't understand the FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK can you please give any example

Comment: @SagarKhurana Let's say you have an activity that serves as a pdf reader and you want to open two separate pdf files. You open the first one and go back and then you open the second one. If your pdf reader activity is launched with the Multiple Task intent (in combination with new document), on your recent apps you will be seeing your app twice; one with the first document open and one with the second. Think your app as a timeline that splits in multiple branches.

Comment: @SagarKhurana here's another example use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119671/how-to-create-the-same-activity-multiple-times-to-have-an-effect-like-google-chr

Comment: thanks for supporting me so much but still I understand first two, not the last  FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK because with and without FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK  I got the same result

Comment: it's not ur fault its mine sorry

Comment: if u are exhausted with this leave it I'm happy that how much u support me

Comment: @SagarKhurana sorry, I'm not generally checking SO on the weekends. Have a look at this photo https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/recent2.jpg this is the Overview or recent apps. Using the MULTIPLE_TASK flag your app can appear more than once on that list and each instance of your app would belong to a separate task. So if for example, you want to have two documents open at the same time you can launch them using that flag and on the overview jump straight from one to the other.

Comment: but this can also be achieved with the help of FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW _DOCUMENT then whats's the difference?

Comment: @SagarKhurana documentation: "NEW_DOCUMENT may be used in conjunction with MULTIPLE_TASK. When used alone it is the equivalent of the Activity manifest specifying R.attr.documentLaunchMode="intoExisting".When used with MULTIPLE_TASK it is the equivalent of the Activity manifest specifying R.attr.documentLaunchMode="always"."You need the combination of the two to create a new task rooted at the activity regardless of whether there's already an existing task of that activity or not. Otherwise, it adds it to the existing task. developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#documentLaunchMode